# change some objects in other SideMenuVC WITHOUT Segua swift3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, delegates

i have a ViewController which is already loaded from the beginning of the app Lunching i need when the user logout from his AccountViewController  ,so the Logout Icon in Side menu got hidden.
So in the Homepage i made that Protocol :

```
protocol HomeViewControllerDelegate {
    func Menucheck()
}
```

then assign the delegate in ViewDidload():

var delegate: HomeViewControllerDelegate?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegate?.Menucheck()
```

then in the Side MenuViewController i did like that:
in ViewDidLoad():

```
let secondVC = Storyborad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
secondVC.delegate = self
```

then i have used the delegate function like that:

```
  extension SideMenuViewController: HomeViewControllerDelegate {
        func Menucheck() {
            print("i can hear you :) ")
            if(preferences.double(forKey: User_ID)  == 0)
            {
                LogoutSideIcon.isHidden = true
            }else {
                LogoutSideIcon.isHidden = false
            }

        }
```

Now when i go to homeViewController i suppose to see ("i can hear you") at least ,but actually nothing happen,i have tried to add to (Viewdidload) instead ,and i have tried to add it to a button action but nothing is happen ...

Comment: Please check that `delegate` is nil or not before this line `delegate?.Menucheck()` ?

Comment: basically it's not possible to do action  other disappear  view controller. you should make store your status any where. checking from there every time   in viewWillAppear to the `SideMenuViewController` for hide and show LogoutSideIcon